# Inkscape: how to add background stripes not overlaying some objects

Tags: inkscape, patterns

I am trying to draw a schema using Inkscape but I am not familiar with the software to make it as I am picturing it. Presently, it looks like that:

[image]

What I would like to add is a strip pattern (color #800000, rotated 45 degrees) but only in the background: meaning not entering the back potato-shaped object and stopping around the written `A' to leave it totally readable.

I have tried drawing a general box, filling it with a pattern, rotating it, moving it to another layer but I was still very far from the end result I would like to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Set the "stripe layer" as the bottom layer;

Add a white **fill** to the circle;

Add a **white-fill-no-stroke shape** centered on the "A", below the A layer but above the stripe layer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use patterns for stripes. I draw them. It's fast. Draw one, ctrl+d duplicate it and ctrl+click drag it over. Do that a few times. Spacing does not matter. When I have four I grab all four and ctrl+d them and move them. Then I grab eight, etc.

Then select all of them, hit ctrl+a to bring up the alignment panel and space them on center.
[image]

Group the stripes by selecting all of them and hitting ctrl+g.

If you need to rotate Hit shift+ctrl+m to bring up Transform.

Draw the circle with White fill.

Use the font tool to draw the A. Then ctrl+d duplicate the A and ctrl+shift+c for Object to Path the duplicated A. At this point I change the fill of the duplicated A to pink so that I can see what I am doing. Add a stroke (also pink) to the A and increase it until you get the perimeter you want for readability. Send the fat A down below the normal A but on top of the stripes. Change the fill and stroke of the fat A to the background color which will create the perimeter.

[image]